# Custom graphql query

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have two graphql queries which return field1, field2 or field1 and field2. Also I have a boolean flags field1 and field2. Could you help me to write the function which will generate one of three qraphql query:

```
gql
    query  {
        employee {
            name
        }
    };


gql
    query  {
        employee {
            surname
        }
    };


gql
    query  {
        employee {
            name
            surname
        }
    }


function Form () {
...
    const { data } = useQuery(
        GET_NAME // query 
    );

    const onClick = () => {

    ....
    return textInput.current!.value=data.me.name;
```

Will execute the query (maybe by `useQuery`) and will return one of possible string:

```
name
surname
name + surname
```

For example:

If I check the name the function will generate and execute query

```
query  {
    employee {
        name
    }
};
```

And will return the value - John

If I check the surname the function will generate and execute query

```
query  {
    employee {
        surname
    }
};
```

and will return the value - Connor

If I check name and surname

```
 query  {
        employee {
            name
            surname
        }
    };
```

And will return John Connor.

Is it works like with SQL query ?

Detail explaining:
Suppose I have only one object on server {name: John, surname: Connor}, without id and other fields. When I call onClick function the client application have to generate and execute only one query. Could you help to do it?

For example if I work with SQL DB, I can concatenate String the query
const q = 
`select ${field}
from employee`

where the fields may by equal "name", "surname" or "name, surname" and generate the queries 
"select name from employee"
"select surname from employee"
"select name, surname from employee"

this query will return the "John", "Connor" or "John Connor".
Is it possible for graphql to generate the query by concatenation or interpolation?

Comment: can you share your actual query and some piece of code?

Comment: I still don't understand the result you are trying to get! do you want to either get name or username if one of them is null or both if they are all defined?

Comment: @Nux Added example

Comment: so what you want is passing field dynamically depending on some situations?

Comment: @Nux I added the explaining, help me please. Is the graphQL Querry a String type variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for graphql to generate the query by concatenation or
>   interpolation?
>   Simple answer is No.

But it can be done if combined with other tools like [graphql-mongodb-projection](https://github.com/du5rte/graphql-mongodb-projection#readme) for mongoDb using mongoose and [graphql-sequelize](https://github.com/mickhansen/graphql-sequelize) using Sequalize.js.

Depending on database and server you are using you will need some tools like those mentioned above for passing required fields to ORM

Comment: Thank u for response. I added the explaining.